# Google analytics cookies are getting rejected in chrome>=80 mode (SameSite=None;Secure; pair enabled)

Tags: javascript, c#, google-analytics

I am working on a fix for new third party cookie rules by google for chrome. Let's assume my website(**say X**) is iframed by some client's website (**say Y**). **X** uses google analytics and it sets some cookies (_ga etc). I have fixed **X** to make compatible with chrome>=80 in third party mode for **Y** but not able to test as cookies set by Google analytics js are rejected for **X** because they are set without `samesite & secure` flags.

My question is, Is there something I need to fix in my code for it OR as I fixed **X** for client *Y*, I should expect same from them.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where these cookies are associated with an Analytics domain, then it's Analytics that's responsible for updating their code to correctly set the `SameSite` attribute. Google Analytics should be on course to update their code before Chrome 80 goes stable in February.

Answer (score 0):

I found raik's answer at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094026/secure-google-tracking-cookies][1] very useful. It set secure and samesite to a value.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
    cookieFlags: 'max-age=7200;secure;samesite=none'
});
```